# jQuery tablesorter external date range filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, tablesorter

I use [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) (a jQuery plugin) with a custom table and I'd like to filter that table with date ranges like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/12/). Unlike this example, I would like to have my date ranges outside the table. I know they have included a way to have a filters outside tables in the last update [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html) . I'd like to know if it was possible. If not, is there a way I can do that with Javascript?

I would like something like this :

```
filter_functions: {

    MySelectBox :{
                "Show all"   : function(e, n, f, i) {
                    return ; // Show all entries
                 },
                "Newest": function(e, n, f, i) {
                    return ; // Today's entries
                 }
    }
}
```

I'm not an expert in javascript so I will appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to go ahead and add all default filter inputs. Add an external select and make it update the internal select; then hide the filter row ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7E7wc/)):

HTML

```
<select>
    <option>Show all</option>
    <option>Newest</option>
    <option>Older</option>
</select>
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th data-placeholder="Show all">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.tablesorter-filter-row {
    display: none;
}
```

Script

```
var $table = $('table'),
    today = new Date().getTime();

$('select').change(function () {
    $table
        // target the 4th (zero-based index) filter
        // and update it with the value from the external select
        .find('.tablesorter-filter').eq(3).val( $(this).val() )
        .change();
});

$table.tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_functions: {
            3: {
                "Newest": function (e, n, f, i) {
                    return n >= today;
                },
                "Older": function (e, n, f, i) {
                    return n < today;
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```